# Where can I find the cde that solves the HMM in PocketSphinx

Tags: python, speech-recognition, hidden-markov-models, pocketsphinx

I am doing a School Project About speech recognition.
As an example of on possible way on how it works, I would like to show PocketSphinx. Sadly, I am unable to find the part of code where the HMM is solved to find the most likely input (voice).

Does anybody know PocketSphinx and how this is done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not familiar with this tool. Yet, first google page leads to its git and there it looks like a C project and not a python one. From fast skimming this look like you are looking for https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/src/libpocketsphinx/hmm.c

Comment: Thank you so much!
That's what I've been loking for. Don't know why I couldn't find it...
And yes, you are right, it is C but I got confused because i use it in a python application.
Have a great day!